# Resolve ActivatedRoute in Angular2 for Dynamic Component by ngComponentOutlet directive

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I want to create Dynamic Component by [ngComponentOutlet](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_component_outlet.ts) directive. 
I have searched almost all of the web for an issue I am facing but could not find anything specific.

Issue: **How can I resolve Dependency of ActivatedRoute for the components to be created dynamically?**

I know I can pass **Injector** to ngComponentOutlet as per examples given [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8578682dcfccc2ccccb68df37c3ebc738f98bf0e/modules/%40angular/examples/common/ngComponentOutlet/ts/module.ts)

But I need to pass dynamic ID or **ActivatedRoute** to component. I am not able to resolve **ActivatedRoute** , Here is a test case:

My.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import { MyService } from './my.service';
import  {Test} from './test'
import { Params,ActivatedRoute}   from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id.toString(),
  selector: 'my-selector',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html'
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit{
   public test: Test;
    constructor(private myservice: MyService,private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params
        .subscribe((params: Params) =>  {this.myservice.getTest(+params['id']).then(test => this.test = test)})
    }



}
```

as you can see **MyComponent** need an **ActivatedRoute** and gets the **ID** from this route and load the corresponding **Test**.
this works fine when I navigate to corresponding url but to create this component Dynamically I don't know how to resolve this **ActivatedRoute** so it gets the required data.

P.S: I thought of passing **ID** as Input() to **MyComponent** but same issue occurs. How to pass Input values to **ngComponentOutlet** ?.

I hope someone help me here

**UPDATED**

Here is components setup for this scenario

**test.ts**

```
export class Test{
id: number;
name: string;
rank: number;
}
```

**my.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="test"> 
ID: {{test.id}}
Name: {{test.name}}
Rank: {{test.rank}}
</div>
```

Here is my dynamic component loader component which keeps record of all the dynamically loadable components.

**list.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import  {MyComponent} from './my.component'
import { Params,ActivatedRoute}   from '@angular/router';

@export class ComponentWrapper{
  component: Component;
  id: number;
  other_data: Object;
  constructor(component: Component,id: number,other_data?: Object){
    this.component = component;
    this.id = id;
    this.other_data=other_data;
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html'
})

export class ListComponent{
   public component_list: ComponentWrapper[];
   public some_ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    constructor(private myservice: MyService,private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }


  addMyComponent(id: number,other_data?: Object)
    this.component_list.push(new ComponentWrapper(MyComponent,id,other_data));
  }
```

**list.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let c_id of some_ids"  (click)="addMyComponent(c_id)" >
Component ID: {{c_id}}
</div>


<div *ngFor="let wrapper of component_list">

<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="wrapper.component"></ng-container>
</div>
```

As you can see. I want to load `MyComponent` dynamically. This component get's the ID from ActivatedRoute and load `Test` from service and shows it's name,id and rank. (This will work fine when some one comes from URL, as router will provider it the `ActivatedRoute` with the corresponding ID)

But when some one clicks on any of the `list` item. I want clicked component(ID) to be loaded dynamically with `ngComponentOutlet`. 
But currently `MyComponent` will not get the required routing information and will fail to load `Test` with clicked ID.

P.S it's a simple demonstrative setup. In real case there will be plenty of Components of different type in `listComponent`

Comment: Why don't you add an abstraction layer between your component and the router? You could inject a custom service into the component which tests the existence of an activated route, and if none is found, use a value you provided.

Comment: But still how would I pass that custom ID to that new service . If I resolve my custom service by `ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([SpecialService])` how would I pass ID to SpecialService , secondly this will require to change every existing component to follow the new scheme. 
There are lot of components I need to load dynamically from different components

Comment: So, returning to your initial problem, you're saying that creating the component dynamically DOES NOT resolve the component's dependency? Can you elaborate? What exactly is not working? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: It does resolve the component dependency as per parent component injector. and I can pass it custom injector too. But how to pass Dynamic services/dependency like ActivatedRoute. 
If we check at https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8578682dcfccc2ccccb68df37c3ebc738f98bf0e/modules/%40angular/examples/common/ngComponentOutlet/ts/module.ts#L31 we can see that's he's passing `myInjector ` to `* ngComponentOutlet` but how to pass `ActivatedRoute` instead of `myInjector` : `ActivatedRoute` with the ID params of `MyComponent`

Comment: I'm not sure I get the "dynamic dependency" part. At the moment when you create the component dynamically, you do have the correct route that is already activated, no?

Comment: okay let me elaborate it. 
Let's say I have a component `MyComponent` which has the dependency on `ActivatedRoute` and it gets the ID from the params and load some data from service depending on that ID. 
Let's say it's route is `HOST/my-components/:id`

Now I have another component named `MegaListComponent` and it's route is `HOST/mega-list` 
Consider it like a table. Now I want to dynamically load the components depending on the clicked row from that MegaListTemplate , Multiple Components are listed and user can click on any of them and they will be loaded on the same page

Comment: now I want to tell the Dynamic Component Loader (ngComponentOutlet) that when you load `MyComponent` pass it the `ActivatedRoute` whose url will be like `HOST/my_components/:id` while the `ID` attributes is dynamic , I want to inject the ActivatedRoute with specific ID, (whichever Component is selected)

Comment: hmmm, I see. What you describe makes me think of the smart vs dumb component pattern. By having your dynamic component talk directly to the router, you're making it too smart. If it only used inputs/outputs to communicate with the outside world, it would be dumber but also more reusable. So, I'm returning to my initial comment: I'd add a "smart component" between the dynamic comp and the router; its job is to fetch the id (from the activated route or elsewhere) and feed it to the dynamic, dumb comp. Sorry if a bit abstract but hard to be more specific without looking at an actual example.

Comment: yeah I got the idea, that I should have a shared service which will be shared across all the components and my Dynamic Component Loader.  

Let me add complete scenarios in question then you can anser it

Comment: I have updated my questions with complete case setup. I hope now you can completely  understand it